# Error when deleting Redux-ORM model instances (many-to-many)

Tags: reactjs, redux-orm

I'm using Redux-ORM to store relational model data in a react project I'm building.

There are two models; Site and Document. The relationship between them is many-to-many. The relationship is defined in the Document Model.

```
export class Site extends Model {
    static get fields() {
        return {
            id: attr(),
            name: attr()
        }
    }
}
Site.modelName = 'Site'

export class Document extends Model {

    static get fields() {
        return {
            id: attr(),
            name: attr(),
            site_ids: many({
                to: 'Site',
                as: 'sites',
                relatedName: 'documents'
            })
        }
    }
}
Document.modelName = 'Document'
```

All is working fine (add/update), except I can't delete a Document that has relationships:

```
Document.withId(action.documentId).delete()
```

Causes an error in Models.js line 734 "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this[key].clear is not a function"

devTools shows that 'this' = SessionBoundModel and 'key' "site_ids"

So it appears to be trying to run the .clear() function on an array. Has anyone else been able to implement deletes on many-to-many? Is my model wrong or is this a bug?

thanks